# How to make a GET request from one component and load a different component only after the response is received in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router

I'm making a React Application wherein, I make a GET request to the server after the user successfully logs in. This process takes time to complete. The user then enters he/she username and moves on to the third page(Component). I want this Component to load only after the response is received from the GET request made previously.

Comment: Please post some sample code so we can get a better idea of what you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

There is no enough information about how do you write the code, what did you try to achieve this but when I need to execute some processes after specific time I'm using setTimeout() javascript built-in method. May be it will help you.

Or... You can create a toggle which control whether first process executed successfully. If you want to share your code example, you can find more helpful recommendations.

Have a nice code pal.